# Can PyPy and Python share a virtualenv or have separate virtualenvs, but active simulatenously?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pypy

Someone on IRC once pointed me out that the habit of `sudo pip install packagename` sooner or later will break my system and advised to use `virtualenv`. I looked into that and I like it, but there is a problem I would prefer to solve before deploying it user-wide. I am used to running the same scripts with either `python` and `pypy`, depending on what is faster. If the script is missing a package, I run `python -m pip install packagename` and when testing PyPy, `pypy -m pip install packagename`. When I tried making virtualenvs for python and pypy (`-p $( which pypy )`) and then running `source path-to-virtualenv/bin/activate` for both,  `python -m pip install packagename && pypy -m pip install packagename` told me while installing the package for PyPy that it's already installed. Does that mean that I can't have two virtualenvs active at the same time?

In other words - can PyPy and Python share a virtualenv or have separate virtualenvs, but active simulatenously?

Comment: I would recommend using miniconda for creating environments. http://conda.pydata.org

Comment: I think it's not possible, like you can't have a single virtualenv containing several versions of CPython.  However you should (again I'm not sure) be able to have two virtualenvs, and never activate any of them, but simply put in your PATH some symlinks to "python" inside the first and "pypy" inside the second.